# Is mysqli_real_escape_string() enough to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, xss

Im using  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for  all database connections in my website. is this enough to prevent ***SQL injection*** ? is there any other precautions ?

Comment: Please read this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @AmitRay thank you very much , really useful information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` does absolutely **nothing** to combat XSS attacks. It combats [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).